# Snackbar and simple button animation

Tags: android, android-snackbar

When using CoordinatorLayout and FloatingActionButton there is automatic animation, when SnackBar appears FAB goes up. But main problem is that FAB is circle and I need button with custom background image.

I could set FAB src, elevation 0dp, background tint transparent, but then problem is that image is too small and this is not acceptable.

Is it possible to add moving up animation (when snackbar appears) and going down (when snackbar is hidden) to simple Button? If possible could you please give solution

Comment: FAB with a background image instead of a plain pop color? Hmmm, that doesn't sound too materialistic...

Comment: look at the source code and see how the FAB handles its animation. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.java?autodive=0%2F%2F